# How to set image in imageview in android?

Tags: android, image, imageview

I want to show an image in imageview so I made a folder - `drawable` in `res` and put my image there. Something like `apple.png`. Then I use this code:

```
ImageView iv= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_selected_image);
String path = getApplication().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(path + "/apple.png");
Drawable icon = new BitmapDrawable(is);
Log.i("Fnord", "width="+icon.getIntrinsicWidth()+
     " height="+icon.getIntrinsicHeight());
iv.setImageDrawable(icon);
```

But when i run it, it said there isn't any image by `apple.png` name in `data/data/package-name/files`. I think i put my image in inappropriate place. Where should i put my image ?

Comment: You also need to make sure that your image isn't going to be stretched https://themillibit.wordpress.com/2017/09/25/why-are-my-bitmaps-all-stretched/

Answer (score 80, accepted):

you can directly give the Image name in your setimage as `iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.apple);` that should be it.

Comment: you mean that i should just write: ImageView iv= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_selected_image);  iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.apple); another code don t need?

Comment: Yes, other code isn't required, but please add your Image in the `res>drawable` and do a `Clean` on the project so that it gets Generated in your `R.java` file (automatically) for referencing.

Comment: There is a folder as `res` created automatically when you create your project, just under that you might be having a folder as `drawable` or you can create it yourself.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of setting drawable resource through code in your activity class you can also set in XML layout:

Code is as follows:

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/apple" />
```

Answer (score 8):

use the following code,

```
    iv.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier("apple", "drawable", getPackageName()));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
// take variable of imageview

private ImageView mImageView;

//bind imageview with your xml's id

mImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.mImageView);

//set resource for imageview

mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_image_name);
```

Answer (score 2):

The images your put into res/drawable are handled by Android. There is no need for you to get the image the way you did. 
in your case you could simply call `iv.setImageRessource(R.drawable.apple)`

to just get the image (and not adding it to the ImageView directly), you can call `Context.getRessources().getDrawable(R.drawable.apple)` to get the image

Answer (score 2):

> if u want to set a bitmap object to image view here is simple two line`

```
Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.sample_drawable_image);
image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        ImageView iv= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_selected_image);
        public static int getDrawable(Context context, String name)//method to get id
        {
         Assert.assertNotNull(context);
         Assert.assertNotNull(name);
        return context.getResources().getIdentifier(name,    //return id
            "your drawable", context.getPackageName());
        }
        image.setImageResource(int Id);//set id using this method
```

Answer (score 1):

If you created `ImageView` from Java Class

```
ImageView img = new ImageView(this);

//Here we are setting the image in image view
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.my_image);
```

Answer (score 0):

*1> You can add image from layout itself:*

```
<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_your_image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:background="@mipmap/your_image"
                android:padding="2dp" />
```

**OR**

*2> Programmatically in java class:*

```
ImageView ivYouImage= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_your_image);
        ivYouImage.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_changeImage);
```

**OR** *for fragments*:

```
View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null, true);

ImageView ivYouImage= (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.iv_your_image);
        ivYouImage.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_changeImage);
```