# CardView's image not showing in a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, cardview

My problem is basically not being able to see a CardView's image when inside a RecyclerView.

I will note that I use this card in other parts of the app and it doesn't make any problem - Also in the card XML are some parts that are also not relevant for this as they are related to an animation when clicking on it.

**EDIT:** I tried the same code, but inflated in `onCreateViewHolder` a different .xml file containing just an image and it worked perfectly... So the problem is narrowed to the `card_layout.xml` not showing the image and the description.

What I'm trying to do is display inside a RecyclerView is this card:
[image]

What I do get eventually is this:
[image]

Generally I'm using a different layout manager, but I'm uploading a code with a standard LinearLayoutManager for the sake of simplicity, also I left some functions empty as it doesn't matter for the sake of this problem:

The Fragment

```
public class FavoritesFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "FavoritesFragment";

    private Context mContext;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private FavoritesAdapter mFavoritesAdapter;

    private ArrayList<String> testData;


    public FavoritesFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_favorites, container, false);

        mContext = getContext();

        testData = new ArrayList<>();
        testData.add("0");
        testData.add("1");
        testData.add("2");
        testData.add("3");
        testData.add("4");

        initRecyclerView(layout, testData);

        return layout;
    }



    private void initRecyclerView(View layout, ArrayList<String> testData) {

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)layout.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewFavorites);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext));
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new FavoritesAdapter(testData, mContext));
        mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new CenterScrollListener());
    }

    private class FavoritesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FavoritesAdapter.ViewHolder> {

        private List<String> data;
        private Context mContext;

        // ViewHolder to hold the card
        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            private View mContainer;
            private ImageView mItemImage;
            private TextView mDescription;
            private TextView mPrice;
            private TextView mShippingDate;

            public ViewHolder(View cardView) {
                super(cardView);

                mContainer = cardView.findViewById(R.id.card_container);
                mItemImage = (ImageView)cardView.findViewById(R.id.card_item_image);
                mDescription = (TextView)cardView.findViewById(R.id.card_description);
                mPrice = (TextView)cardView.findViewById(R.id.card_description);
                mShippingDate = (TextView)cardView.findViewById(R.id.card_shipping);
            }
        }

        public FavoritesAdapter(List<String> data, Context context) {
            mContext = context;
            this.data = data;
        }

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.card_layout, parent, false);

            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return data.size();
        }


    }

}
```

fragment_favorites.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.panasonixx.asosplus.FavoritesFragment">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerViewFavorites"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</FrameLayout>
```

card_layout.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/card_container"
    cardview:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    cardview:cardElevation="4dp"
    cardview:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
            android:layout_above="@+id/card_description">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layoutButtons"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:visibility="gone">

                    <Button
                        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                        android:text="@string/card_reveal_buy" />

                    <Button
                        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                        android:text="@string/card_reveal_share" />

                    <Button
                        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/card_reveal_favorite" />


                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/card_item_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/image"
                android:src="@drawable/test_image"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="@string/price"
            android:id="@+id/card_price"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_margin="2dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="@string/shipping"
            android:id="@+id/card_shipping"
            android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/card_price"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="@string/desc"
            android:id="@+id/card_description"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_above="@+id/card_price"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/card_shipping"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/card_image_description"
            android:id="@+id/card_shipping_icon"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_local_shipping"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/card_shipping"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/card_shipping" />


    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not binding views to row in `onBindViewHolder` method, use it like :

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder,final int position) {
    final ViewHolder myHolder = (ViewHolder ) holder;
    Favourite fav=Favourites.get(position);
    holder.mItemImage.setImageBitmap etc ...
```

Comment: I'm inflating the card_layout.xml directly - I'm not using any data, you are right it will be that way but for now I only want to see it displayed

Comment: Then in your fake data define integer and add `R.drawable.yourdrawable`

Comment: is this necessary even though I inflate an XML that already defines the src of the image?

Comment: it doesn't hurt to try , only several lines of code.

Comment: @bluesummers can you follow codepath's recyclerview guide and let me know if you still have issues : https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview

Comment: well I've just edited the original post seems like the problem is in `card_layout.xml` as when I tried the same code only inflating in `onCreateViewHolder` a different .xml containing an image only all worked perfectly - seems pretty weird to me

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken you forgot to set the image on the `ImageView`.
**i.e** `mItemImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.apple);`

**Reference :**

[How to set image in imageview in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513953/how-to-set-image-in-imageview-in-android)

Comment: The resource is attached already on the XML file the ViewHolder is not doing anything by now, it's only a template for future functionality

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things that could be going on.

First off, what is the size of that image? If it's quite large, it might be failing to load the bitmap properly. I doubt this is the issue if it's loading in other parts of the app ok, but definitely a consideration.

You've got kind of a strange set up for your layouts. It's recommended to avoid using nested layouts as much as possible as they can impact performance. You mentioned that you omitted some stuff due to animations, but I strongly suggest you make some changes either way. If you are able to give me a full picture of what the layout is supposed to look like, I can tweak this; but here's a rough idea:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/card_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
cardview:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
cardview:cardElevation="4dp"
cardview:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutButtons"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <Button
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:text="buy" />

        <Button
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:text="share" />

        <Button
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="reveal" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/card_item_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="image"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_above="@+id/card_price"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_dashboard_black_24dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/card_price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:text="price"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/card_shipping"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/card_price"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:text="shipping"
        android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/card_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/card_price"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/card_shipping"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="desc"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/card_shipping_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/card_shipping"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/card_shipping"
        android:contentDescription="desc"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_event_black_24dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Chances are, you should be able to get rid of that LinearLayout with the buttons, but I couldn't really tell where you wanted it to go.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ryan, though I'm using the card template from here https://github.com/4k3R/material-sharing-card that's why I need the nested layout, one for the background popping, and second one for the buttons showing