# How to use drawable resource from library module in to our application module?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-appcompat

I am using android studio 2.1.3, 
i have import compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23+'. Now i want to use images from appcompat library in my application module. Please give reply as soon as possible.

I have attached screenshot. Please check image.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set image in imageview in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513953/how-to-set-image-in-imageview-in-android)

Comment: Please see this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/70844512/12272687

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that.Most of the resources in appcompat library is private.This library has public.xml in res/value of it and only the resources defined in this xml are accessible and the rest of the resources are implicitly private and android wouldn't give you suggestion to use them.Your best bet is to download a copy of it and put it in the drawable of your own application so you will be able to refer to them.
Resource: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html

Answer (score 1):

For xml-
Make an imageview.

Write this inside the image view-

```
android:src="@drawable/name"
```

and it shall work

[image]

So now click on the clip art icon and there are hundreds of icons and pics. They are probably the same as of the external libraries. Click next for whichever image you want and that will be added to your drawable folder and then you can use it.

Comment: I know how to use. I want to use images from library in my module. did you get it ?

Comment: In your main app go to the drawable folder. Right Click new>>Image Asset>>Icons and select the images you want

Comment: Yes this works. but this is not my solution. I want to use res. folder of library. for ex. appcompat library has its own res. right? then i want to use images from that library in to my application module.

Comment: Like:   
<ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/abc_ic_clear_mtrl_alpha"/>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133523/discussion-between-nilesh-patel-and-knattic).

Comment: Yes i know this. But this is not answer to my question. did you get it?

Answer (score 0):

Add imageView in xml and add background.

```
android:background="@drawable/any_image_you_want"
```

Comment: I know how to set drawable. my question is why appcompat images not display in module?

Comment: If you have added dependencies in gradle file it will surely be visible in your module you can access appcpmpat res folder but you can't see it in Android module you can go inside project and see res folder in appcpmpat

Comment: As per your attached image you are seeing res folder through project structure if you go to Android it will not be visible but as it is added as library to your module you can access it

Comment: Yes i can access it. but not display auto suggestion in my layout.

Comment: Whatever is exposed that will be definately visible as per my knowledge.

Comment: You can clean built and try